# Нужен скрипт, берущий содержимое из одного div и вставляющий его в другой div

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Всем привет, нужен скрипт который сможет взять содержимое из одного div и вставить его в другой div на той же странице.

К примеру

```
<div><a href="#">необходимая, динамичная ссылка</a></div>
<p>lalalalalal lalalal lalalla</p>
<div>вставить ссылку сюда</div>
```

спасибо!

Comment: Для начала попробуйте разобраться самостоятельно и, в случае, если что-то не будет получаться, задавайте конкретный вопрос "что именно не получается".

Comment: Вопрос из серии: - Петька приборы?! - 120! - Что 120?! - Что приборы!
Опишите более подробно проблему, и принцип отработки нужного Вам скрипта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
~function () {
  var a = document.getElementById('a')
  var b = document.getElementById('b')

  var df = document.createDocumentFragment()
  
  for (var c of a.childNodes) {
    df.appendChild(c.cloneNode(true))
  }
  
  b.textContent = ""
  b.appendChild(df)
}()
```

```html
<div id=a>123 <a href="#">необходимая, динамичная ссылка</a> 456</div>
<p>lalalalalal lalalal lalalla</p>
<div id=b>вставить ссылку сюда</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML
```

```html
<div id=a>123 <a href="#">необходимая, динамичная ссылка</a> 456</div>
<p>lalalalalal lalalal lalalla</p>
<div id=b>вставить ссылку сюда</div>
```